Single Items using audit trail (audit.net)
I am playing with the library audit.net to track changes. I want to use sql data provider and the extension for entity framework. I updated the db context to inherit from AuditDbContext. It works fine so far and stores data to database.
But i want to query the data to be shown in a frontend application. So i need to query by primary key. At the moment it is stored in the json, but multiple items in json because the audit is for the complete transaction.
Is there any way to configure the existing data provider / extension to write one audit per database object changed? Additionally is what is the preferred way to expose the primary key ... because the key could be named differently per table.

If you have access to the audit database via Entity Framework, consider using the Entity Framework data provider instead.
This data provider will store each entity modification into a separate row in the database.
For example, your audit table mapped to a class like this:
[AuditIgnore]
public class AuditLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuditJsonData { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
    public string AuditUser { get; set; }
    public string TablePrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

Configuring the data provider to map each entity to the AuditLog table and extracting the primary key from the audit event:
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(_ => _
        .UseDbContext<MyDbContext>()
        .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
        .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, entity) =>
        {
            entity.AuditJsonData = entry.ToJson();
            entity.EntityType = entry.EntityType.Name;
            entity.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.AuditUser = Environment.UserName;
            entity.TablePrimaryKey = entry.PrimaryKey.First().Value.ToString();
        })
        .IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));


Thanks, i give it a try and let you know if it works for us.
